# "Can't connect to MySQL server on" error when connecting to an external MySQL server

Tags: php, mysqli, database-connection

We recently updated PHP to the latest version, and we had a PHP script that was running that is now broken.

Currently, it is not even allowing me to connect to the SQL database at all, and is returning this error:

> Failed to connect to MySQL: Can't connect to MySQL server on mysql01.fau.edu (13) 2003

The database itself is located in a Linux environment and I currently cannot get even a simple script as the one below running:

```
$host = 'mysql01.fau.edu';
$username = '*****';
$password = '*****';
$database = '******';
$connect = mysqli_connect($host,$username,$password,$database);

if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    echo 'Failed to connect to MySQL: ' . mysqli_connect_error() . mysqli_connect_errno();
} else {
    echo 'Connected to MySQL! </ br>';
}
```

Comment: The database is running on a _remote_ machine, or on the same machine you're testing this PHP script from?

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/access-denied.html

Comment: The error suggests the port is unavailable (firewalled, etc). If you just `telnet mysql01.fau.edu 3306` do you get a successful socket open?

Comment: Did this exact script work using your old version of PHP?

Comment: The database is running on a remote machine.

The exact script does work using an older version of PHP on my laptop.

Comment: I did do the telnet, and it returned with an open connection.

Answer (score 1):

For security purposes Mysql is not remotely accessible by default, unless you whitelist the allowed IP in the backend.

You have mentioned it used to work on your laptop which could very possibly change IP.

Use the same network when it was working

Answer (score -1):

Just guessing...but check to make sure you can connect to mysql from the command line.  If so...double check your php.ini.  Sounds like php.ini may have been overwritten with the upgrade.  Make sure you have the extensions for mysql enabled.

Answer (score -1):

mysqli connect stopped working from version 5.5 upwards, from php 7 updwards, it was removed and will give you a http ERROR 500 refer to the link below

["Call to undefined function mysql_connect()" after upgrade to php-7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34088373/call-to-undefined-function-mysql-connect-after-upgrade-to-php-7)