# I am using xampp server and trying to run localhost but constantly getting an error in connect.php

Tags: php

hey I am using xampp and trying to run localhost but constantly getting an error in connect.php...error is as follows

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function
>   mysql_connect() in C:\xampp\htdocs\admin panel\connect.php:9 Stack
>   trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\admin panel\index.php(16): include() #1
>   {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\admin panel\connect.php on line 9

my connect.php code is as follows

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
mysqli_connect($servername,$username,$password) or die('cannot connect to  
the server'); 
?>
```

please help me out with this.

Comment: strange, error says `mysql_connect` and the code has `mysqli_connect`. Both are different functions from different extensions `php_mysql` and `php_mysqli`. Check if these extension are enabled in php.ini.

Comment: yes it's strange. Actually `mysql_*` is deprecated from PHP5 and removed from PHP7. So may be somewhere  in your code you used `mysql_*` and that's why you get that error. B

Comment: `$con = mysqli_connect($servername,$username,$password) or die('cannot connect to  
the server'); 
if($con){
  echo 1;
}else{echo 0;}` add this and share the result

Comment: @devpro its fatal error, script won't go ahead. :)

Comment: than chk the answer what he is saying, or also check the version by `php info function`

Answer (score 0):

Uncomment the line extension=php_mysql.dll in your "php.ini" file and restart Apache. if its not working then update your xampp with latest version.

Answer (score 0):

Warning This extension was deprecated in PHP 5.5.0, and it was removed in PHP 7.0.0. Instead, the MySQLi or PDO_MySQL extension should be used. See also MySQL: choosing an API guide. Alternatives to this function include:

```
mysqli_connect()

PDO::__construct()
use MySQLi or PDO

<?php
$con = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'username', 'password', 'database');
```

check this ["Call to undefined function mysql_connect()" after upgrade to php-7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34088373/call-to-undefined-function-mysql-connect-after-upgrade-to-php-7)

refer this link for mysqli extension help http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mysqli_connect.asp