# PHP5 application is not working in PHP7 live server (ubuntu 16.04) -

Tags: php, web-services, ubuntu, server, server-administration

I have a php application. Its built in php (raw php). In my local pc its running. but when I upload to live server (ubuntu 16.04) then it doesn't work.

I have installed all php dependencies in Live server ... Still the files are not working. I found some problem in live server as given below:

1. Raw PHP (5.4 version coded ) is not working
2. Class does not call from Index.php file
3. When I run `exit("OK")` its return `OK` but page not running
4. when I add a class like `$doc = ClassName::getInstance();` its not running.. Returns `NULL`

I think I made very silly silly mistakes. Here is the live server info :

1. IP 35.160.167.129
2. info.php : http://35.160.167.129/info.php => its running

Would you please help me how do I resolve this issue. Thanks in advance

Comment: Anything show up if you turn error reporting on? -> `ini_set('display_errors', 1); error_reporting(-1);`?

Comment: have you given the permission to files

Comment: could you please define "not working"? also, AFAICR, PHP5.4 is outdated. just as i side note.

Comment: @Darren : yes its showing error : 

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysql_connect()

Comment: Have you used proper namespace and imported it correctly? @Selim Reza

Comment: @sunilwananje : I set all files permission

Comment: @PassionInfinite : yes .. cause its the same as local pc

Comment: @SelimReza okay, just a wild guess: your new server has PHP7.... **don'
t** use `mysql_`-functions, they are deprecated for *quite some time* now and in PHP7, completely **removed**. port your application to `mysqli_` or `PDO`.

Comment: @SelimReza  replace mysql_connect() to mysqli_connect

Comment: @selimReza solution given by FranzGleichmann is perfect. PHP7.0 does not have mysql_ functions they are deprecated!

Comment: going to replace `mysql_` to `mysqli_` ... I will update you asap

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Call to undefined function mysql\_connect()" after upgrade to php-7](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34088373/call-to-undefined-function-mysql-connect-after-upgrade-to-php-7)

Comment: @FranzGleichmann : somehow its returns `Warning: mysqli_connect(): (HY000/1698): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'` all the time .. did I miss anything for database permission flush ?

Comment: @SelimReza well, **that** error message is more than obvious. you are not allowed to connect to your database with the credentials you specified in your code configuration. just fix them. oh, and you should *never* use root for anything but administrative operations.

Comment: @FranzGleichmann : I fix the issue. Thank you so much

Comment: @Darren : I fix it .. Thank you so much

Comment: @sunilwananje. I fixed it ... Thank you so much

Comment: @PassionInfinite : Thank you so much